# GCC 4.0.2 dereference pointer to double type member of structure raises SIGBUS error

Tags: c, gcc, struct, java-native-interface, sigbus

The follow sample code looks OK to me but always fails executing on Solaris with SIGBUS error if compiled with GCC 4.0.2, however it runs fine if compiled with GCC 3.4.2 version. Any thought?

```
        //params is a pointer to a structure Param, which has a member d whose type is double. It was initiated/allocated through JNI.

        params->d = 5.0;
        double *b = &params->d;
        double c = params->d;
        c += *b;
```

SIGBUS was raised at the last line, i.e. dereferencing the pointer and accessing the content is causing the problem.

Thanks,
Charles

Comment: How was `params` allocated? Which line triggers the SIGBUS?

Comment: Sorry I left that info out. params is allocated through JNI. It fails at the last line and raises SIGBUS. It seems to me OK to create a pointer to the double member but dereferencing it and accessing the content is failing.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the generated code and/or stepping through the code with gdb ?

Comment: gdb shows the type of b is (double *) and its referenced value is 5.0.

Comment: SIGBUS normally means that the alignment of the address is wrong (e.g. for `double` it is not a multiple of 8). Check what address causes the error and how it was accessed (look at the disassembly). Perhaps gcc 4.0.2 miscompiles this fragment.

Comment: Thanks. Re-examing the structure definition, it has packed attribute. The structure is mixed with fields of double, int and other structures with int members. The code is following:

Comment: #define __PACK_ATTR __attribute__((__packed__))

Comment: struct tagP_DATE
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    }__PACK_ATTR;

typedef tagP_DATE DATE_P;

Comment: #define __PACK_ATTR __attribute__((__packed__))

typedef char *SHCODE;  // for short codes

struct tagP_DATE
{
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
}__PACK_ATTR;

typedef tagP_DATE DATE_P;

struct tagP_DATA
{
    long iPDebug;              
    DATE_P dp_1; 
    DATE_P dp_2;
    DATE_P dp_3;
    DATE_P dp_4;   
    int count;
    double r[1024];
    double r2[1024];
    DATE_P dp_5[1024];
    double dM;
    int iF;
    int iB;
    char *sz;
    int iC;
    ...
    int iT;
    double d;
    SHCODE sc;
    int iL;
}__PACK_ATTR;

typedef tagP_DATA PARAMS;

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like an alignment issue to me. IIRC, `double` has to be aligned to 64 bit.

Comment: According to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html, "Note: The 4.1, 4.2 and 4.3 series of GCC ignore the packed attribute on bit-fields of type char. This has been fixed in GCC 4.4 but the change can lead to differences in the structure layout. See the documentation of -Wpacked-bitfield-compat for more information." Could the char type member cause the misalignment under GCC 4.0.2? My structure is defined with packed attribute for legacy reasons.